# Matching two array with flexibility

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, types

I work on an app Ionic with on array with ingredients and a service with recipe who look like this->

[image]

So I need to match ingerdients with the recipe. I start to do this :

```
 this.truelist = [...this.spliterStrIngredients()]; // my arrayof ingredients
 const  nbIngredients = this.truelist.length;

 console.log('true list = ' + this.truelist);
 let match = 0 ;
 this.recipeList.forEach((key => {
     key.ingreds.forEach(ingrRecipe => {
         this.truelist.forEach((ingrSelct , index) => {
            if (ingrSelct === ingrRecipe)
            {
                match ++;
            }
            if (match >= this.truelist.length ) {
                this.recipeMatch.push(key.name);
                match = 0;
            }
         });
     });

 }));
 console.log(this.recipeMatch);
}
```

So it works when I select exactly the same recipe but I would like to be more flexible for example I have in the array pasta+cheese+carrots but I can match with carbonara.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I cannot figure out your flexible rules of matching. It's better if you can state the exact rules of flexible matching. I don't know much about how to make Carbonara (lol)

Comment: So Carbonara = [pasta ,cheese ] but I would a match even if I have more ingredients. For example I have in my ingredients [ pasta, cheese, othersIngredientsMore]. I mean if I have the good Ingredients and more in my array it's matching. I don't if it's clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the rules you presented, here goes a solution that fits your needs:

```
const recipeList = [{
    name: 'Carbonara',
    picFile: '',
    ingreds: ['Pasta', 'Cheese', 'Egg'],
    description: ['1', '2', '3']
}];

const myIngredientsA = ['Pasta', 'Cheese'];
const myIngredientsB = ['Pasta', 'Cheese', 'Egg'];
const myIngredientsC = ['Pasta', 'Cheese', 'Egg', 'Bacon'];

function findMatchRecipe(myIngredientsList: string[]) {
    let count = 0;
    let recipeMatch: any[] = [];

    recipeList.forEach(recipe => {
        recipe.ingreds.forEach(ingredient => {
            if (myIngredientsList.includes(ingredient)) {
                count++;
            }
        });
    
        if (count === recipe.ingreds.length) {
            recipeMatch.push(recipe.name);
        }

        count = 0;
    });

    console.log(recipeMatch);
}

findMatchRecipe(myIngredientsA); // doesn't find a match, since the 'Egg' is missing
findMatchRecipe(myIngredientsB); // finds a match, since all ingredients match
findMatchRecipe(myIngredientsC); // finds a match, since all ingredients match independent of the extra ones
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your explanation, I come up with the following solution.
I'm not familiar with typescript, so I programmed in pure JavaScript as follows:

```js
const carbonara = ['pasta', 'cheese'];
const menuA = ['pasta', 'cheese', 'carrot'];
const menuB = ['pasta', 'tomato'];
const menuC = ['carrot', 'pasta', 'cheese'];

const flexibleMatch = (menu1, menu2) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < menu1.length; i++) {
    if (!menu2.includes(menu1[i])) {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(flexibleMatch(carbonara, menuA)); // true: menuA includes all ingredients in Carbonara plus carrot
console.log(flexibleMatch(carbonara, menuB)); // false: menuB doesn't contain cheese
console.log(flexibleMatch(carbonara, menuC)); // true: ingredients order doesn't matter
```

Comment: @Clementwdk I add a menuC as you said, you can try it on jsfiddle or somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works but if I have menuA = [carrot,pasta,cheese]
It returns false i would like it works with items in any way

Comment: Do you reply to my solution?
I tried that input and it works well.
Please upvote me if you find it's okay. 
I would appreciate that